# Android Studio version of an Excel vlookup?

Tags: android, android-studio

Ok I'm a massive noob and apart from following lots of tutorials I like to set myself a problem and then try to fix it with an app.  Therefore I'm trying to make a little app that'll help me when I'm at work.

Basically it needs to breakdown a 4 character string into it's individual characters and then display them phonetically.  So if I (the user) type in 5F9A then it'll display FIVE FOXTROT NINE ALPHA.  At work we have an excel spreadsheet that does this all and I'm just trying to reverse engineer it.  The spreadsheet itself has multiple stages, it reads the characters, converts them into ASCII and then performs a vlookup on a range of cells where each ASCII code is next to it's phonetic pronunciation.  It looks for the number 53 (5 in ASCII) and then looks at the cell next to it which says FIVE.

I've managed to translate any user input into ASCII but I just don't know how to store and access this next set of data.  I've been looking into SQLite but that is waaaaaay beyond me at the moment and seems far to complicated for something this simple?

Anyway, I know it's cheating asking for the answer, but maybe a push in the right direction?

Comment: You could store everything in a HashMap<String,String>

Comment: Cool thanks for the reply, I'll look into this and the other comment.  What's the major difference between a hash map and a switch case - baring in mind I've not learned either yet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dummy way to do that would be:

- Get every letter (char) of the word
- Have a switch case that gives you the phonetic equivalent (you will have to do that by hand)

  String word = yourWord;
  String phonetic;
  char currentChar;

  ```
  for(i=0;i<=word.lenth();i++){
      currentChar = word.substring(i, i+1);
      phonetic = getPhonetic(currentChar)
  }

  String getPhonetic(char char){
      switch char{
           case a:
               return alpha;
               break;
           case b:
  ....
       }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply it'll be a few days before I can experiment but that's given me something to aim for! Thanks again.